# How can I make very small blur effect?

Tags: css

How can I make very small blur effect with -webkit-filter (or filter), between 1px and 0?

I've already tried something between 1em and 0.01em but as far as this filter is recalculating this to pixels and below if it's drops below 1px then is no blur at all..

Comment: cannot be done with CSS3 filters. You can use svg images, you can blur those to lower than 1px. Don't know too much about them though, sorry.

Comment: if it's less than one px, it will only be visible when the user zooms in a lot, so is it really worth it?

Comment: Yes, I've see quite big difference between 0 and 1px. That why I ask this question..

Comment: "if it's less than one px, it will only be visible when the user zooms in a lot, so is it really worth it?" - You can see difference easy (without zooming) on images

Answer (score 1):

here is a quite complex solution which involves duplicating some content:
http://jsfiddle.net/BWj28/1/

It works by replicating the content box 4 times, shifting the replicants by 1 pixel in every direction and calculating the approppriate opacity for the replicants. The version above requires an opaque background.

```
      ---
      -a-
      ---

 ---  con  ---
 -d-  ten  -c-
 ---   t   ---

      ---
      -b-
      ---
```

HTML sample layout:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a t">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="b t">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="c t">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="d t">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="content">Hello World!</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.a,.b,.c,.d {
    position: absolute;
}
.a { top: -1px; left:  0px; z-index:1; opacity:1;     }
.b { top: +1px; left:  0px; z-index:2; opacity:0.5;   }
.c { top:  0px; left: +1px; z-index:3; opacity:0.333; }
.d { top:  0px; left: -1px; z-index:4; opacity:0.25;  }
.wrap > div {
    background: yellow; /* any opaque background */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One think i want to tell you this type of features in not applied in CSS3 because it doesn't have full support but the future of CSS may provide this feature...

Anyways `-webkit-filter` are only applicable in chrome only...
So, codes like that can be useful to you,

```
img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
}
```

Refer this: [**Click...**](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit)